# sms gateway hub transactional API

Tags: php, api, sms-gateway

I have below API for sms gateway for transaction sms.

```
https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=**************&senderid=WEBSMS&channel=2&DCS=0&flashsms=0&number=8888888888&text=test%20message&route=1
```

but i am getting below response.

```
<SmsResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ErrorCode>006</ErrorCode>
<ErrorMessage>error:Invalid template text</ErrorMessage>
<JobId/>
<MessageData i:nil="true"/>
</SmsResponse>
```

can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi HimanshuUpadhyay,

You need to contact smsgatewayhub for the support.
They will setup on SMS template on their gateway for Sample templates Follow:

http://support.smsgatewayhub.com/solution/articles/3000024886-sample-templates-for-transactional-route

After you will able to Send SMS.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try reducing the differences with their example:

- Use `http`
- remove the %20

Try with a real phone number, not 888888888

Comment: that is not an issue. i have given this for reference only. it gives another error for invalid mobile number.

Comment: There is nothing to try, we can directly get response if correct credentials.